# GCP Datafusion - No se puede conectar a SQL Server (VPN protegida)

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, gcp

La idea es conectarme a una base de datos SQL Server que se encuentra protegida por una VPN a través de Data Fusion y cualquier otro servicio de Google que quiera utilizar.

El error que me figura es el siguiente: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Leyendo en varios artículos me decían de configurar una IP Privada desde la instancia de Datafusion, pero como para la conexión a esa base es necesaria en otras herramientas, ¿cómo se podría agregar esa IP a nivel proyecto en GCP?

Comment: En algún lado de la documentación ha de estar la manera de incluir una regla al firewall.